# Will Plugging A Windows Fomatted Storage Drive Into A Computer Running Ubuntu Automatically Format It?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

So if I have a SSD running Windows and a larger regular hard drive that has personal files and games, and I take out that larger hard drive and put it in with a another computer that has an SSD running Ubuntu, will the regular hard drive be automatically formatted and the files lost, or will it still be able to be used? This isn't what I'm going to be doing, but I just want to know the principle of it. I want to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows from a single SSD, but I want another storage drive for my windows OS to store games on, and I don't want the Ubuntu one to mess with it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

If it is connected as an external (say, USB) drive, then Ubuntu will try to automatically mount it so that you can access the files. If it is connected as an internal drive, Ubuntu will not try to mount it by default.

In neither will case will it try to format the disk.